# Вызвать конструктор наследника в абстрактном классе

Tags: java, ооп

Как вызвать в абстрактном классе конструктор того класса, конкретно который его наследует? Типа такого:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public Abstract foo() {
        //Когда метод foo вызовется наследником
        AbstractClass a = new this(); //здесь надо вызвать конструктор наследника
        a.bar(); //как-то меняем состояние, вызывая метод наследника
        return a; //и возвращаем экземпляр наследника
    }

    public abstract void bar();
}
```

Но в данном примере выдает ошибку:

> java: as of release 8, 'this' is allowed as the parameter name for the
>   receiver type only, which has to be the first parameter

Comment: Или вы заплутали в трех соснах, или я не понял вопроса. Зачем вам создавать экземпляр наследника, если метод `foo()` уже является экземплярным? Берете экземпляр наследника и просто вызываете у него метод `foo()`. А еще лучше сразу `bar()`.

Comment: @NikBond  Базовый и тем более абстрактный класс ничего не знает о своих наследниках и более того не должен знать. Если у вас возникает такая проблема, то значит вы неправильно спроектировали классы.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Мне как раз необходимо чтобы базовый класс выполнял действия, которые однотипны для всех наследников, без информации от том, кто конкретно его наследует. 
Т.е. когда метод базового абстрактного класса вызывает конкретный наследник, наследник мог создать экземляр своего класса, как описано в методе.
Это разве не вписывается в хороший дизайн?

Comment: Просто вызывайте в методе `foo()` метод `bar()` и делайте `return this`. В итоге даже если у вас есть некий наследник A, то вызвав в нем `foo()` вы получите что хотите.

Comment: ТС нужно виртуальное клонирование или виртуальный метод фабрика - NewInstance.

Comment: @Chubatiy Тащемта возвращать мне нужно не объект который вызвал foo, а именно новый объект a того же класса, над которым произвели изменения bar.

Comment: вместо `new this()` попробуйте `getClass().newInstance()`

Comment: @Chubatiy , спасибо, это как раз то, что нужно в данном случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде всего в хорошем дизайне базовый класс ничего не должен знать о своих наследниках, иначе нарушается одна из основ ООП о программировании по контракту.

Сделайте еще один абстрактный метод и переопределяйте его в наследниках таким образом, чтобы они возвращали новые экземпляры своего типа:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public AbstractClass foo() {
        AbstractClass a = createInstance();
        a.bar();
        return a;
    }

    public abstract void bar();

    protected abstract AbstractClass createInstance();
}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    protected override AbstractClass createInstance() {
        return ConcreteClass();
    }
}
```

Если все-таки не хочется трогать наследников и пойти грязным путем, то можно использовать рефлексию (однако в таком случае у всех наследников должен быть конструктор без параметров):

```
public Abstract foo() {
    AbstractClass a = this.getClass().newInstance();
    a.bar();
    return a;
}
```